# WSGI app can not receive post method from html form

Tags: python, html, web, web-applications, wsgi

hello I just started to program for the web with python without use of any web framework.
for testing reasons I created a simple html form with the post method to pass a simple text data to the WSGI app that I wrote.
this is the code for the HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/tester" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user"> 
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the code for the simple WSGI app:

```
def test_app(environ, start_response):
    var1 = str(environ["REQUEST_METHOD"]) 
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return[var1]
```

but no matter what I do it keeps showing me GET!(as the purpose of the code is tho return the method).
I don't know what I need to do?

Comment: The function returns GET because environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] is 'GET'. Did you check the environ variable set for the REQUEST_METHOD?

Comment: The purpose of the function was to print the request method. The request method as you can see is set to "post" but it keeps showing GET instead.